# Google Analytics Core Reporting API; OR filter with custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm attempting to use the Google Analytics [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) to query for some filtered sessions data. Filter A returns results, filter B returns results, but applying filter A OR B returns no results. Am I missing something?

Filtering by one custom dimension with an exact match:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: OAuth <redacted>"
     "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
        ?ids=ga:<redacted>
        &metrics=ga:sessions
        &start-date=2014-06-01
        &end-date=2016-05-25
        &filters=ga:dimension1==MyMatchString"
```

Returns

```
<dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:sessions" type="integer" value="12345"/>
</dxp:aggregates>
```

Filtering by another custom dimension with an exact match:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: OAuth <redacted>" 
     "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
        ?ids=ga:<redacted>
        &metrics=ga:sessions
        &start-date=2014-06-01
        &end-date=2016-05-25
        &filters=ga:dimension2==MyMatchString"
```

Returns

```
<dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:sessions" type="integer" value="67890"/>
</dxp:aggregates>
```

But filtering with either custom dimension having an exact match

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: OAuth <redacted>" 
     "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
        ?ids=ga:<redacted>
        &metrics=ga:sessions
        &start-date=2014-06-01
        &end-date=2016-05-25
        &filters=ga:dimension1==MyMatchString,ga:dimension2==MyMatchString"
```

Returns no results:

```
<dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:sessions" type="integer" value="0"/>
</dxp:aggregates>
```

I also tried these same requests with v3 of the API but had the same result.

Comment: Are the results similar on web interface ? Also try setting `samplingLevel : HIGHER_PRECISION` .

Comment: @Kola Setting `samplingLevel : HIGHER_PRECISION` had no effect. By web interface do you mean https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ ? I can't use that to test this because I don't own the Analytics account to authorize it--it's one of our client's and I only have the refresh_token.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Could it be that your that the custom dimension hit level are different and can never be true together for the metrics that you are looking up?
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

What are the hit levels or details of each dimension in use?